# MySQL SELECT query on junction table with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, junction-table

I have four tables, assuming they have only an id as a column each.

- `listings`
- `feature`
- `location`
- `l_f_location` as a junction table with FKs on `listingId`, `featureId`, `locationId`

I try to query the `l_f_location` table for a given set of `locationIds` (logical AND match) and want as a result only those listings which match ALL the `locationIds`, e.g. (7 AND 9 AND 10).

`l_f_location` looks like

```
listingId featureId locationId
10        5         7
10        7         7
10        8         9
11        4         7
11        8         9
11        9         10
11        12        14
```

The goal is to retrieve only `listingId` 11 in this case - matching the set of `locationIds` 7, 9 and 10.

I tried the following query

"`SELECT id, COUNT(*) as num FROM l_f_locations WHERE locationId IN ( 7, 9, 10) GROUP by listingId, locationId HAVING num = 3`"

But that gives wrong values of count as the grouping kicks in.

A similar query works perfectly on a simpler junction table e.g. only l_location with e.g. "`SELECT id, COUNT(*) as num FROM l_location WHERE locationId IN ( 7, 9, 10) GROUP by listingId HAVING num = 3`".

Rgds,
P.

Comment: in the first query why are you including `locationId` in the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: I group by listingId and locationId to reduce the results to what I would like to count per listingId.

Comment: No, I am looking for a listingId which has 7,8,9. It might have other, but that is fine in this query.

Comment: Added another line in the l_f_location table - so listingId 11 would still match, has having 7,9,10.

Comment: that's what i'm confused of, you have already a working query but you want to add `locationID` in the group by clause which i don't understand. sorry

Comment: No, I do not have working query. I have one for another, more simple junction table, e.g. l_location (no featureId FK).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the same `listingId` and `locationId` can have multiple `featureId`s? Otherwise it's quite a bit easier.

If that is the case:

```
SELECT listingId, COUNT(*) as num 
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT listingId, locationId
 FROM l_f_locations
 WHERE locationId IN ( 7, 9, 10)) AS sub
GROUP by listingId, HAVING num = 3
```

Comment: Yes, you assumed correctly. The inner select needs to be aliased, so i tworks like

`SELECT listingId, COUNT(*) as num 
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT listingId, locationId
 FROM l_f_locations
 WHERE locationId IN ( 7, 9, 10)) AS foo
GROUP by listingId, HAVING num = 3`

Comment: Great. Let me know whether it works. If not, it might be easiest to create a SQL Fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I'm testing as I speak, it looks good so far. Will do some more testing and then accept your answer. Many thanks!

Comment: Does it fail without an `AS` clause? I think it should still work.

Comment: Yes it fails with #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've updated that answer with that.